# Misunderstanding during phone interview; how to negotiate pay

Tags: salary

Three days ago I was called by a company recruiter. I had applied at many jobs and did not know specifically which company was calling me and for which task.

He first asked if I was still looking for a job, and then asked what my price range was. I just said 18 dollars an hour. He asked me what the least was, and I said 15 if it's easy. He said ok and claimed he would be contacting me soon.

This morning, he emailed me claiming that he would be passing my resume to his supervisor (good). In that email, he included a link to the current job description. After reading the job description, it is apparent that I will need **at least** 20 per hour, based on the difficulty of the tasks presented in the job description.

Should I wait until they respond and initiate the hiring process, and then re-elaborate on the salary?

Something like "After viewing the job duties, I will need at least 20 per hour."

What's your recommended plan of attack?
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Once I get to my computer, I should probably do some research on the salaries that company pays out obviously

Comment: What industry are you in? Regardless of what you said, the recruiter probably heard "Wants $18 but will work for $15" and ignored the part about easy vs. hard jobs. I've never really heard of someone in my industry (software development) charging differently based on that aspect. Silly though it may be, often the rate is based more on the person than the work.

Answer (score 6):

Call the recruiter ASAP. Tell him exactly what you said here -- that you had applied at many jobs, and didn't realize he was inquiring about a job that required these specific tasks.

Then tell him you need $20/hr for that job, nothing less, because of the job description and amount of work to be performed. Make it clear you are a perfect match for that job and that you'd be a great hire and tell him why (experience, skills, references, etc).

The recruiter is on your side -- he gets a commission based on your rate, so he's motivated to help you get a higher paying job. At the same time, he wants repeat business, so he's also motivated to make sure his client (the company) hires a perfect fit (you) so that they'll use his recruiting services again.

This question is probably better suited for [workplace.stackexchange.com](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), but that's ok.

Comment: The recruiter doesn't get paid at all if the deal doesn't go through. The deal is more likely to go through if the rate the employer gets charged is lower. Of course the deal won't go through at all if it's below what the candidate will accept.

Comment: The recruiter, my friend, is never on the side of the employee.

Comment: @bharal the recruiter is on his own side, and as stannius said, he only gets paid if both the employer and candidate are happy enough with each other to seal the deal.

Comment: Recruiters are hired _by the company recruiting_, not the employee.  Their best interest is placing someone, anyone who can do the job will fulfil their obligation and get them paid.  If that person is cheaper and may be more likely to get selected because of that, then they will put them forward.

Comment: @JaneS Of course they usually get paid a percentage of the negotiated salary so it's also in their interest to get someone in with a higher salary.

Comment: @Eric that is the story recruiters sell you.  they are paid by the company,  and part of their strategy is to help the company reduce costs. a recruiter who increases the employees salary will get more money in the short term,  but probably won't be used by the company again

Comment: @bharal I have never had a discussion with a recruiter about how they can help us reduce costs.  I have had conversations with them about how someone with a salary expectation 25% higher than what we're looking to pay is not a suitable candidate.  I'm much more interested in the recruiter finding **good** candidates in the salary range than finding **cheap** candidates.

Comment: If the recruiter is an agency/staffing firm, then it is in their best interest to pay their employees the least amount possible, to increase their margin.

Comment: @Eric do you have a role in deciding which recruiting company to bring on?  or are you just a dev manager?